# Popen getting pid of newly run process

Tags: ruby, linux, io, popen, pid

I want to run some application in background and later kill it by pid.

```
pipe = IO.popen("firefox 'some_url' 2>&1 &")
pipe.pid
```

This code starts firefox and return me some pid, but unfortunately it's not firefox's pid.

```
pipe = IO.popen("firefox")
pipe.pid
```

This code starts firefox and return mi some pid, firefox's pid.
Is there any solution to start external application and get its pid? Firefox is only for example it could be any other application. I also tried with libs like: Open3 and Open4 but seems to be the same effect. 
I also wonder if '$!' bash variable is good solution for this? Run something in background and read '$!', what do you think?

Comment: Is it the pid of any runninng process? In general the command you start with popen can spawn any number of other processes so if you want a specific pid  from those you need to find some other way of identifying the process you are after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are running it in the background (`command &`), you get the interpreter's PID:

```
>> pipe = IO.popen("xcalc &")
>> pipe.pid 
=> 11204

$ ps awx | grep "pts/8"
11204 pts/8    Z+     0:00 [sh] <defunct>
11205 pts/8    S+     0:00 xcalc
```

Drop the `&`:

```
>> pipe = IO.popen("xcalc")
>> pipe.pid
=> 11206

$ ps awx | grep "pts/8"
11206 pts/8    S      0:00 xcalc
```

For the additional issue with the redirection, see @kares' answer

Answer (score 4):

it's not just about running it in the background but also due `2>&1`

redirecting err/out causes `IO.popen` to put another process in front of your actual process ( `pipe.pid` won't be correct)

here's a detailed insight: http://unethicalblogger.com/2011/11/12/popen-can-suck-it.html

possible fix for this could be using `exec` e.g. `IO.popen("exec firefox 'some_url' 2>&1")`

Comment: Indeed, I completely overlooked this.