# Get PID while process in ruby

Tags: ruby, pid

I have simple ruby script which execute `wget` command. And I need to get `pid` of this(`wget`) process

```
wget = `wget <options>`
pid = `ps aux | grep <options>`
```

But main problem that I can get pid while script is executing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popen getting pid of newly run process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366071/popen-getting-pid-of-newly-run-process)

Comment: backticks are only for simple command execution. For anything more involved (like getting the pid) you need to use `IO.popen` or similar:  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-popen

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate link, it appears to be a more involved question, and the answers there do not answer this one.

Answer (score 2):

`` `cmd` `` waits for the command to finish, but [`spawn`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) should work:

> This method is similar to #system but it doesn’t wait for the command to finish.

```
pid = spawn('sleep 3') #=> 45376

# do something while process is running

Process.wait pid # wait for process to finish
```

Comment: I wonder how to kill the PID process after an application has exited irregularly. I need this for a ruby-gtk application where mpv is used to play radio streams; right now I have a zombie process. I know the PID, but I am not sure of an elegant way to kill the PID when the ruby-gtk application crashes. Don't want to use a big rescue-clause here.

Comment: @shevy sounds interesting, you should post a question.